# What is the meaning of this pun: "planphlet"?

Tags: meaning, puns

In a [recent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FqXTCvDLeo) (exactly [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FqXTCvDLeo&t=54s)) there was a term used, "planphlet":

> ... a plan printed on a pamphlet. PLANPHLET!

which I believe is a pun, but I can't decipher what it relates to.

From context I believe it means that the plan proposed to fight the climate crisis is somehow not adequate.

To be exact, I am interested in what makes it a pun, e.g what "-phlet" means here, what makes it a pun.

Comment: It's just a play on the previous spoken line: "a plan printed on a pamphlet".

Comment: Why not as answer? Right, I didn't notice this is a separate word, and I didn't knew its meaning. Thanks!

Comment: So, it is not a pun.  Instead it is a "portmanteau word" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau

Comment: Please give a transcription with a full sentence (and maybe one or two sentences before.

Comment: It's a DIY 'portmanteauing', non-standard and as not a recognised word, off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Killing Time commented, *planphlet* is a combination of *plan* and *pamphlet*.

It is not a pun.  Instead it is a ["portmanteau word"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau)

> a blend of words in which parts of multiple words are combined into a new word, as in *smog*, coined by blending *smoke* and *fog*, or *motel*, from *motor* and *hotel*.

Comment: And, just for the record, a true pun relies on being able to find multiple meanings in the same sound, whether because different words sound the same ("I tried to make you laugh with ten puns, but no pun in ten did" ["in ten did" == "intended"], or because a word has multiple meanings, some of which might be humorously relevant ("Hey baby, wanna come fishing with me?" "Oh, I think you're going to need a stronger line" [fishing line vs pickup line])